# Getting System.ListException: Duplicate id in list:

Tags: apex, trigger, callout, after-trigger

I am getting "System.ListException: Duplicate id in list: " in After trigger.How to prevent this.I am trying to update the same record after callout in after trigger.Below is my piece of code:

```
List<Patient_Package__c> lockPackage = new List<Patient_Package__c>();
if(trigger.new[index].Approval_Status__c=='Approved'){

            lockPackage.add(new Patient_Package__c( id=trigger.new[index].id,ECC_Sync_Status__c=label.PMM_ECC_STATUS_Processing));
            try{
            ECC_protocol_Sub_Callout.ecc_protocol_subscription(string.ValueOf(trigger.new[index].id));
            lockPackage.add(new Patient_Package__c( id=trigger.new[index].id,Approval_Status__c=''));
            }catch(exception e){
                PMM_Exception_DAO.insertExceptionRecord(e,'ECC_Onboarding_Callout','ecccallout');
                system.debug(e.getmessage());
            }
        }
        if(lockPackage!=null && !lockPackage.isEmpty()){
            update lockPackage;
        }
```

Comment: Of course you are getting this error...you are trying to add the same record to the update list twice and setting two different `Approval_Status__c` values. Are you trying to clear it out or set it to the `Custom Label` value? You can't do both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your use case you can easily use map.

```
map<Id,Patient_Package__c> lockPackage = new map<Id, Patient_Package__c>();
if(trigger.new[index].Approval_Status__c=='Approved'){

            lockPackage.put(trigger.new[index].id,new Patient_Package__c( id=trigger.new[index].id,ECC_Sync_Status__c=label.PMM_ECC_STATUS_Processing));
            try{
            ECC_protocol_Sub_Callout.ecc_protocol_subscription(string.ValueOf(trigger.new[index].id));
            lockPackage.put(trigger.new[index].id,new Patient_Package__c( id=trigger.new[index].id,Approval_Status__c=''));
            }catch(exception e){
                PMM_Exception_DAO.insertExceptionRecord(e,'ECC_Onboarding_Callout','ecccallout');
                system.debug(e.getmessage());
            }
        }
        if( !lockPackage.isEmpty()){
            update lockPackage.values();
        }
```

This will remove your duplicate Id error.

**PS** As you are doing this in trigger then you should use before update and write your code there because in this way you need to handle **recursive trigger** error. And in before update you don't need DML.

Comment: @tushar-its correct